# PreparateStatement execution stopped while Lock appears With SpringJdbc

Tags: java, locking, spring-jdbc

On client environnement, we face a Lock on table.
To reproduce, we lock manually table on our local environnement.

We need to create block code that continue execution and don't stop when this lock occured.
But with SpringJdbc it's stop execution.

Here is my code that are correctly executed and not stopped:
IN our code OracleRepositoryJdbcTemplateImpl.

```
@Override
public int[] update(final String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss,
               final String queryName) throws DataAccessException {
   long start = executionStart();
   try {
      return execute(sql, new PreparedStatementCallback<int[]>() {
                  @Override
                  public int[] doInPreparedStatement ( final PreparedStatement ps)throws SQLException {
                  ... Code that are correctly executed
                  logger.warn("********** SQLException");
                  return int[1];


               }
            }
      );
   } finally {
      System.out.println("********** Finally of the update method");
      queryStop(start, queryName);
   }
}
```

and org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate:

```
public <T> T execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)
      throws DataAccessException {

   Assert.notNull(psc, "PreparedStatementCreator must not be null");
   Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      String sql = getSql(psc);
      logger.debug("Executing prepared SQL statement" + (sql != null ? " [" + sql + "]" : ""));
   }

   Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getDataSource());
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try {
      Connection conToUse = con;
      if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null &&
            this.nativeJdbcExtractor.isNativeConnectionNecessaryForNativePreparedStatements()) {
         conToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeConnection(con);
      }
      ps = psc.createPreparedStatement(conToUse);
      applyStatementSettings(ps);
      PreparedStatement psToUse = ps;
      if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null) {
         psToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativePreparedStatement(ps);
      }
      T result = action.doInPreparedStatement(psToUse); // HERE
      handleWarnings(ps);
      return result;
   }
   catch (SQLException ex) {
      // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
      // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
      if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
         ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
      }
      String sql = getSql(psc);
      psc = null;
      JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
      ps = null;
      DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
      con = null;
      throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("PreparedStatementCallback", sql, ex);
   }
   finally {
      if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
         ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
      }
      JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
      DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
   }
}

public <T> T execute(String sql, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
   return execute(new SimplePreparedStatementCreator(sql), action);
}
```

It's block execution in this class at line of comment HERE.
The log ********** SQLException is show, but the execution never go to our finally blocks.
'con' and 'ps' Object from JdbcTemplate are showing "Collecting data...".

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: What this: Connection conToUse = con; and this:  ps = psc.createPreparedStatement(conToUse); try to organize better your code?

Comment: It's SpringJDBC code,  not mine. ^^

Answer (score 0):

To fixed it, we nested our code execution in a Callable function:

```
@Override
public int[] update(final String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss, final String queryName) throws DataAccessException {
    Callable<int[]> call = new Callable<int[]>(){
         @Override
         public int[] call() throws Exception{
              return updateInCallable(sql, pss, queryName)    
         }
         public int[] updateInCallable(final String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss, final String queryName) throws DataAccessException {
         // Our code
         }
    }             
}
```